change structure of a csv file in R
I am currently working on a csv file data wrangling, i have a feature "track" that has several values for the same instance, like a list of data points. I want to create a loop to split these values in order to have them stored in two new columns : lat and lon instead of track.
Here is an example of I would like to change it :
Hos it is now :
 structure(list(startTime = 1673652576000, endTime = 1673652605000, 
    track = "Any[Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38113329424818, \"lon\" => 8.488552397519989), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38115806843576, \"lon\" => 8.488606700331793), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38117942217475, \"lon\" => 8.488750238611077), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381191813557656, \"lon\" => 8.488831542342021), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38119496242752, \"lon\" => 8.48889035827453), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381129867348655, \"lon\" => 8.488894804346009), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38110967635605, \"lon\" => 8.488808354980387), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381089123104935, \"lon\" => 8.48873929104632), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381083177776155, \"lon\" => 8.488731425037434), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38105863930372, \"lon\" => 8.48866144565764), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381069428672866, \"lon\" => 8.488639684187174), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38105328464012, \"lon\" => 8.48861185403874), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38101967503413, \"lon\" => 8.488536802144624)]", 
    distance = 64, transitMode = "walk", oldTransitMode = ""), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

How i want it to be :

Can anyone help please ?

You should post the original data as text in your question, e.g. by copying and pasting the result of dput( thedata ).

In the absence of a usable example I can't show a work-through, but dplyr::separate_wider_delim() may be a place to start.  Are there always the same number of coordinates in each "track" entry?

apologies, I meant tidyr not dplyr

Thanks, I put the original data as text now. Hope it can help. @user2554330

It looks like a python file or xlsx? (I'm likely wrong), but not a traditional .csv (header, data, sep) that would need some further parsing to then parse as csv. How was this originally saved?

The track entries are written in some language that I don't know, but the general approach would be to strip out all the "wrapper" code, then split each entry into multiple entries.  I'd do it with a for loop over each entry in the dataframe.  Others would probably use other methods.
For example:
thedata <- structure(list(startTime = 1673652576000, endTime = 1673652605000, 
               track = "Any[Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38113329424818, \"lon\" => 8.488552397519989), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38115806843576, \"lon\" => 8.488606700331793), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38117942217475, \"lon\" => 8.488750238611077), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381191813557656, \"lon\" => 8.488831542342021), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38119496242752, \"lon\" => 8.48889035827453), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381129867348655, \"lon\" => 8.488894804346009), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38110967635605, \"lon\" => 8.488808354980387), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381089123104935, \"lon\" => 8.48873929104632), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381083177776155, \"lon\" => 8.488731425037434), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38105863930372, \"lon\" => 8.48866144565764), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.381069428672866, \"lon\" => 8.488639684187174), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38105328464012, \"lon\" => 8.48861185403874), Dict{String, Any}(\"lat\" => 47.38101967503413, \"lon\" => 8.488536802144624)]", 
               distance = 64, transitMode = "walk", oldTransitMode = ""), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

result <- data.frame()
for (i in seq_len(nrow(thedata))) {
  track <- thedata$track[i] |>
    gsub("Dict\\{String, Any}\\(", "",x = _) |>
    gsub("Any\\[", "", x = _) |>
    gsub("]", "", x = _) |>
    gsub("\\)", "", x = _) |>
    strsplit(",")
  track <- track[[1]] |>
    gsub('"lat" => ', "", x = _) |>
    gsub('"lon" => ', "", x = _) |>
    as.numeric()
  j <- 2*seq_len(length(track)/2)
  lats <- track[j-1]
  lons <- track[j]
  entry <- data.frame(
    startTime = thedata$startTime[i],
    endTime =   thedata$endTime[i],
    lat = lats,
    lon = lons,
    distance = thedata$distance[i],
    transitMode = thedata$transitMode[i],
    oldTransitMode = thedata$oldTransitMode[i])
  result <- rbind(result, entry)
}
result
#>       startTime      endTime      lat      lon distance transitMode
#> 1  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38113 8.488552       64        walk
#> 2  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38116 8.488607       64        walk
#> 3  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38118 8.488750       64        walk
#> 4  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38119 8.488832       64        walk
#> 5  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38119 8.488890       64        walk
#> 6  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38113 8.488895       64        walk
#> 7  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38111 8.488808       64        walk
#> 8  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38109 8.488739       64        walk
#> 9  1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38108 8.488731       64        walk
#> 10 1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38106 8.488661       64        walk
#> 11 1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38107 8.488640       64        walk
#> 12 1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38105 8.488612       64        walk
#> 13 1.673653e+12 1.673653e+12 47.38102 8.488537       64        walk
#>    oldTransitMode
#> 1                
#> 2                
#> 3                
#> 4                
#> 5                
#> 6                
#> 7                
#> 8                
#> 9                
#> 10               
#> 11               
#> 12               
#> 13

Created on 2024-04-11 with reprex v2.1.0
You should check each step on your real data; it might not be all structured the same.
BTW, there are shorter ways to do this, but they are much more obscure.  If you convert the {} pairs to (), and the => to just =, then you can parse the track as R code, and read out the numbers from the resulting expression.  For example,
track <- parse(text=gsub("\\{", "(", track) |> gsub("\\}", ")", x=_) |> gsub("=>", "=", x=_))
lons <- sapply(3:length(track[[1]]), function(i) track[[c(1,i,2)]])
lats <- sapply(3:length(track[[1]]), function(i) track[[c(1,i,3)]])

This is pretty obscure code; I prefer my longer answer above.

Any thoughts on startTime/endTime conversion? as.POSIXct(result$startTime[1], origin = "1899-12-30") [1] "54935-12-07 16:20:00 EST"

@Chris:  I'd need to see some times in the spreadsheet to have any hope of that.

Hello all, thank you so much for your time :) It works :) Regarding the time it is epoch milliseconds format, how can I change it in R ?

@sikimimi:  Show us some of the times, and it will be easy.  You'd use as.POSIXct, passing whatever time is 0 as origin.  You will need rescaling too:  convert values to seconds instead of milliseconds.
